# AMQP (Node.js) for RabbitMQ close connection too early

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have the following code, and it's giving me the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertQueue' of undefined
    at /var/www/myapp/dashboard/routes.js:195:39
    at /var/www/myapp/node_modules/amqplib/lib/callback_model.js:46:16
    at /var/www/myapp/node_modules/amqplib/lib/callback_model.js:61:10
    at /var/www/myapp/node_modules/amqplib/lib/callback_model.js:74:5
```

If I comment out conn.close(), and the code works fine, and I think the code is trying to close the conn too early, before the execution of ch.assertQueue. What is the best way to fix this problem?

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'blast_queue';
    var msg = blast.id;

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg), {persistent: true});
    console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
  });
  conn.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the connection closure happens before the callback function in `conn.createChannel` is executed.
To fix it, move the line where you close the connection inside callback function:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'blast_queue';
    var msg = blast.id;

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg), {persistent: true});
    console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
    conn.close(); // <=== close connection here
  });
});
```

Comment: amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'blast_queue';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.prefetch(1);
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);

    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
        console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: false});
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

From:

`amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {`

To:

`amqp.connect({ protocol: 'amqp', hostname: 'localhost', port: 5672, username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx', vhost: '/' }, function(err, conn) {`